# Java JodaTime - 29.02.2024 - Value 29 for dayOfMonth must be in the range [1,28] - leap year

Tags: java, date, jodatime, leap-year

I use this code in my application:

```
final DateTime selectedDate = new DateTime().withMonthOfYear(month).withDayOfMonth(day).withYear(year);
```

where `month` = 2, `day` = 29, `year` = 2024

and I get this exception:

```
Value 29 for dayOfMonth must be in the range [1,28]
```

but 2024 is a leap year.
Does anyone have a solution about this?

Comment: Try calling `withYear` first, before the other `with` methods.  That way, you won't have an invalid intermediate result.

Comment: Please clarify which certain year we are talking about? The title states `2023` but question body contains `2024`. In this case is relevant I guess.

Comment: This issue might be related to https://github.com/jodaorg/joda-time/issues/132 and/or https://github.com/jodaorg/joda-time/issues/131 where the DE incorrectly doubled down on that errant behavior reported.

Comment: The error is correct if you actually used 2023; if 2024, report the bug

Comment: @Andrew This is no bug. `new DateTime()` gives a date in the current year, 2023, not a leap year, so setting the month to 2 and then the day of moth to 29 gives 29 February 2023, a non-existing date. That the code after that *would have* set the year to 2024 is not relevant because the exception causes that never to happen. Dawood Ibn Karieem is perfectly correct that the order matters.

Comment: I would it do it this terse way: `final DateTime selectedDate = new DateTime().withDate(2024, 2, 29);`. On my computer it just gave me `2024-02-29T19:36:29.350+01:00`.

Comment: @Ole V.V.  What does the .withYear(year) with tear = 2024 do? Nothing, with no error?

Comment: OK, I see it now, so it uses inits with default of 2023, and parese left to right; so what if the order was changed--that should work: ".withMonthOfYear(month).withDayOfMonth(day).withYear(year)" ==> ".withYear(year).withMonthOfYear(month).withDayOfMonth(day)" (basically what 
Dawood ibn Kareem said early on above).  Also, DateTime(2024, 2, 29, 1, 1, 1, 1) should work.  Thanks. :-)

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem  Why not post that as the Answer?  Seems you are correct.

Comment: @Andrew OK, done.  When I saw this question last week, I didn't have time to write a proper answer.  That was then - this is now.

Answer (score 6):

Whereas the final value of your expression appears to be a valid date, you've evaluated it in an order which requires an invalid date to be evaluated along the way.

You wrote

```
final DateTime selectedDate = 
    new DateTime().withMonthOfYear(month).withDayOfMonth(day).withYear(year);
```

which is evaluated from left to right.  It's therefore equivalent to

```
DateTime result1 = new DateTime().withMonthOfYear(month);
DateTime result2 = result1.withDayOfMonth(day);
final DateTime selectedDate = result2.withYear(year);
```

Now, suppose I run this today (20 March 2023) with `month = 2, day = 29, year = 2024` as you specified.  Then I have

```
DateTime result1 = 20 February 2023 // all good so far
DateTime result2 = 29 February 2023 // whoops!
```

and this is the point where your exception is thrown.  We never got as far as setting the year to 2024.

Rearranging your code so that `withYear` gets called first would fix this, because all the intermediate results would be valid dates.

```
final DateTime selectedDate = 
    new DateTime().withYear(year).withMonthOfYear(month).withDayOfMonth(day);
```

A better idea is Ole's idea

```
final DateTime selectedDate = new DateTime().withDate(year, month, day);
```

which sets all three fields in a single call, so you don't need to be concerned about intermediate results.

But the best idea of all would be for you to use the classes in the `java.time` package, instead of Joda.  Joda has been obsolete for almost 10 years now.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

// ...

final LocalDate selectedDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
```